# class extend variable scope in unityscript

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Let me be more specific here:  This is used in Unity 2017 so the syntax they are using is this:

```
class CameraMotionBlurEditor extends Editor 
{   
  var preview : SerializedProperty;
  var previewScale : SerializedProperty;
...
  function OnInspectorGUI () {
    if (preview.boolValue) dosomething()
  }
}
```

What I'm getting errors in is this `preview.boolValue` reference.. it claims it's ambiguous so therefore whatever this class is extending, must also have a declaration of that variable name.  What I don't know is how to specify the local one.

Comment: `this.preview.boolValue`

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword is used to refer to the  current instance of the class. Retrieving the `preview.boolValue` from the current instance of the class hence becomes `this.preview.boolValue`:

```
function OnInspectorGUI () {
  if (this.preview.boolValue) dosomething()
}
```

Note that UnityScript is [slowly becoming deprecated](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/08/11/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset/), and the recommended route of action is to instead program Unity scripts in C#.